# How to use Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) for protecting certain paths for Cloud Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-load-balancer

I'm using google [Cloud Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing) for exposing dashboard. This load balancer was created by GKE ingress. I want to restrict certain endpoints with specific pattern to be accessible with organization email. eg. `*/internal/*`.

I've tried to use [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto) but it's restricting all URLs.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that.